# How recognize and change to unknown font?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

First, I apologize, as I know it may be a basic question, and unfortuantely it is very personal, so cannot be used by the community!

I like to change the original font of my template dissertation file! From the readme file, I know the initial setup is CMSS! But I could not find where the font is setup. The first line in the enclosed snapshot shows the original font, but I want to use the font in the second line!

So I have two questions:
1) how can I find the font type used in the second line. Is there any archive for the SS fonts?
2) How I can use the \renewcommand to change the font in this case?

[image]

P.S. from the main source files, I see both lines have the same fontsize 12. But the characters in the second line seem darker. Is this due to font type or is it changed by a command?

Comment: So what is this second similarly-looking font?

Comment: @Werner unfortunately, I do not know! Is there any archive of SS fonts, where I can look up for the fonts used in a sentence? There is a command in the main file of the second template though, as \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ma1}

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, so here it goes:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ma1}
```

Lets you use Microsoft Windows fonts. In this case, ma1 stands for Arial and \rmdefault sets the default roman (serifed) font family. By the way, Arial is sans-serif.

Comment: I tried the Arial font in Microsoft Office and it matches the font used in the second line of my snapshot. Many thanks for your helpful hint! But using the same renewcommand did not change the font in Latex. I used \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ma1} after \documentclass definition, but nothing changed. By the way, I am using XeLatex to compile the main file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but if you are looking for a font, there are online tools that help you identify a font via a screenshot. Using [Whatfontis](https://www.whatfontis.com) and your image above, it lists up to 60 similar-looking fonts:
[image: Results from what font is website]

If you are looking for your installed texfonts, that depends on your OS and your tex installation. On Ubuntu + TeXLive, it's `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts`, provided you have the fonts packages installed.